# Can you count the spots on a 6x6 grid to calculate the probability one fair pair of dice when rolled has a sum greater than another fair pair of dice?

Tags: probability, dice

Can you count numbers on a $6\times 6$ grid to calculate the probability one pair of dice when rolled has a sum greater than another fair pair of dice?

You can calculate the number of grid spots for every place on the grid where the spot's sum exceeds that of the selected grid value and count that number and divide by $6^4$, but is that the probability one pair of dice exceeds another identical pair of dice?

I know the sample space is $6^4$

if the first roll is a (1,1) the number of spots on a 6x6 greater than that is 35/36.

If the first roll is a (1,2), the number of spots on a 6x6 grid greater than (1,2) is 33/36.

Continue until you hit 36 spots and summed the corresponding spots with a sum greater than that

I imagine this probability is (35+33+...)/6^4

Comment: You need a 6x6x6x6 table, if you want to count

Comment: Don't try to fit your whole question in the title. The title is supposed to summarize, not be the whole question.

Comment: And what d9 you mean by "spots?"

Comment: What do you th8nk the number after $33$ will be?

Comment: The reality is, it will be have the time when the two aren't equal. So you really need to count the probability the two will have the same value, subtract from $1,$ and divide by $2.$

Comment: This will give: $$\frac12\left(1-\frac{1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+5^2+6^2+5^2+4^2+3^2+2^2+1^2}{6^4}\right)$$